# Regarding moving the serialized file based on a condition through java

Tags: java, file-io

I have to make a program to copy the serialized files from a source folder to target folder only if the target folder does not contain that
serialized file, so the first condition is to check whether the file that i am copying is already existed in target folder or not
if it exists then do not need to copy but if does not exists then copy, so this check of whether file exists or not is need to be done 
at every second

source folder is C:\ter\
target folder is C:\bvg\

file to be transffered is gfr.ser

I have come up with this below program but still check is not implemented please advise how can I implement this check also..

class ScheduledTask extends TimerTask {

```
public void run() {
    InputStream inStream = null;
    OutputStream outStream = null;

    try {
        File source = new File("C:\\ter\\");
        File target = new File("C:\\avd\\bvg\\");

        // Already exists. do not copy
        if (target.exists()) { 
            return;
        }


        File[] files = source.listFiles();
        for (File file : files) {
            inStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(target + "/" + file.getName());

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            // copy the file content in bytes
            while ((length = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                outStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            inStream.close();
            outStream.close();
        }
        System.out.println("File is copied successful!");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

```
    the above approach is not working
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`exists`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists%28%29) method of [`java.io.File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html) class like this.

```
 public void run() {
        InputStream inStream = null;
        OutputStream outStream = null;
        try {
            File source = new File("C:\\ter\\gfr.ser");
            File target = new File(" C:\\bvg\\gfr.ser");
            if (target.exists()){   // Already exists. do not copy
                 return;
            }
            inStream = new FileInputStream(source);
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(target);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            // copy the file content in bytes
            while ((length = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                outStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            inStream.close();
            outStream.close();
            System.out.println("File is copied successful!");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I want to make an executable jar of this program please advise how can I do this

Comment: Go to the **classes** folder and run the command **`jar -cf MyJar.jar *`**

Comment: exists should work. This is the only method we have in java to check the file presence.